# how to type OR sign on MAC (swedish keyboard)

Tags: macos, input, keyboard

This is a really silly question but I can't figure it out... how on earth do I type the OR sign on a MAC?? Swedish keyboard layout.

Found a post suggesting Alt+Shift+L but that doesn't work (maybe because my keyboard is swedish?).
Found another post suggesting Alt+Shift+i but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>, that's work on mine :

[image: keyboard]